# Mockito when() method not working and getting null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, springmockito

I am writing unit test cases using Mockito and JUnit . But getting `NullPointerException` when running a test. On debugging I get to know that Mockito on method:  `when().thenReturn()` is not returning a value for dependent methods and the calling program is calling those methods to get result.

Below is my dummy code to get idea of structure of code:

```java
class B {
  public C getValue() {
    return C;
  }
}

class A {
  public D getAns(String q1, String q2) {
    return B.getValue().map(mapper::toD); //null pointer exception start here 
  } 
}

@RunWith(MockitoJunitrunner.test)
class TestA {
  
  @InjectMock
  A a;

  @Mock
  B b;
  C c;

  init() {
    when(b.getValue()).thenReturn(c);
  }

  @Test
  public void getA() {
    D ans=A.getAns(q1,q2);  //getting null pointer exception here 
    AssertNotNull(ans);
  }
}
```

Comment: Use @Mock to C c

Comment: There is nothing to inject into A and looks like `getValue()` is a static method. If that isn't the case please add code that represents your case.

Comment: getValue() is not static . and my code is exactly like above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have classes calling each others methods so it is better to use `Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`

In your Case:

> `A` is calling `B` and `B` is calling `C`

Just replace:

```
 @InjectMock
  A a;

  @Mock
  B b;
  C c;
```

With :

```
A a = Mockito.mock(A.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
B b = Mockito.mock(B.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
C c = Mockito.mock(C.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
```

Comment: A is calling B and B is calling C

Comment: @SakshiMishra then use `A a = Mockito.mock(A.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
B b = Mockito.mock(B.class, Mockito.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);` instead of simple mock. Try it and let me know if you still get NPE ??

Answer (score 1):

There may be multiple reason to why `when(...).thenReturn(...)` is not called :

1. The data type which is used in when construct is not matching exact, for example, if you have a string and you pass null, its not same method call
2. Ensure that the objects are getting initialized using the same approach. A spring injected resource is not same as the one created using new operator

Comment: This helped me track down my issue - with the combination of non-matching arguments and RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS, mockito was returning mocked stubs instead of what I was intending it to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use @InjectMock and @Mock to solve this issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).